# runtime error in java mysql connectivity

Tags: java, mysql, database, netbeans-7

Now i get a run time error. 'java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException:Not yet implemented'
how can i restore it.

```
 private void btnlogActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

    user=txtuser.getText();
    char[] pass=jPasswordField1.getPassword();
    String passString=new String(pass);
    try{
      Connection con = createConnection();
      String sql = "INSERT INTO login(username,Password) VALUES ('" + user + "','" + passString + "')";
      Statement st = con.prepareStatement(sql);
      st.executeUpdate(sql);
    }
    catch(Exception e){
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Exception: "+ e.toString());
    }
  }
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    try {
      Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
      String connectionUrl = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/Stock?"+
        "user=root&password=";
      Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"SQL Exception: "+ e.toString());
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException cE) {
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Class Not Found Exception: "+ cE.toString());
    }
  }
```

Comment: i think a full stacktrace would be more helpful. SO can you please add full stacktrace

Comment: Post more code (enough so we can see whole picture), and whole stack trace.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Answer (score 1):

Ok i found the problem. You have `Statement` reference which points to `PreparedStatement`  object. But `PreparedStatement`doesn't have any method `execute(String)` which you are using.It has method `execute()` without any argument. Thats the source of problem. Moreover this is not the right way to use `PreparedStatement`. You should use either `Statement` , the way you have written the query , or you can see how `PreparedStatements` works [here](http://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/jdbc-preparedstatement-example-batch-update/) .

Answer (score 0):

Use `java.sql.PreparedStatement` in a correct way, EG:

```
 java.sql.PreparedStatement statement= con.prepareStatement("delete from song where no=(?)");
```

Set the variables:

```
    statement.setInt(1,id);
    statement.setInt(2,...);
    sta...
```

**UPDATE:**

An EG as requested:

```
import com.mysql.jdbc.Statement;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;


public class Insert {
public static void main(String args[]) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException    {


insert("e:/helloJDBC");

              }
public static void insert(String path) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException
{int id=1;


         Connection con = null;
  Statement stmt = null;
    String dbUrl = "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/song";//your db
 String dbClass = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";

 Class.forName(dbClass);
con = DriverManager.getConnection(dbUrl,"root","sesame");//enter reqd. fields
    java.sql.PreparedStatement statement= con.prepareStatement("insert into song values(?,?)");//Whatever your query
    statement.setInt(1,id);
    statement.setString(2,path);//set as per the order of ? above
    statement.execute();
    System.out.println("1 row effected");



     }


}
```

Comment: Do you want a sample short Example?(And by execution do you mean result set?)